# Noetherianity of $\mathbb{R}^+$

Tags: order-theory, noetherian

I have some confusion about some properties of noetherian posets. I am defining a poset $X$ to be $\textbf{noetherian}$  if every ideal of $X$ Is finitely generated. I am trying to show that this is equivalent to the statement: $X$ has the descending chain condition (DCC) and no infinite anti chains.

Before I even prove this, though, I wanted to make sure it made sense to me, and I immediately came up with a counter example in my mind (of course this counter example is wrong, but I cannot see why! This is what I need help in).

Consider the poset $(\mathbb{R}^+,\leq)$. I believe every ideal of $\mathbb{R}^+$ is finitely generated. In fact, it seems that all ideals of $\mathbb{R}^+$ can be written as the interval $[a,\infty)$ , and thus all ideals are generated by a single principle ideal.

However, the DCC on $\mathbb{R}^+$ does not seem to hold. For if we take the sequence 
\begin{equation}\frac{1}{1},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},...\end{equation}
It never stabilizes.

There must be something very wrong in my understanding, can someone help clarify what I did wrong here?

Thank you!

Comment: Is $(1,\infty)$ an ideal?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown  Yes I believe it is. Are you saying this is a non finitely generated ideal?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: How are you defining ideal?  As a down directed, upper set?

Comment: @WilliamElliot I define an ideal $I$ as: If $x\in I$ and If $x\leq y$ then $y\in I$. Lord Shark the Unknown, Yes I think that does answer my question Thank you :)

Comment: That is not an ideal.  It is an upper set. @jgcello